# script error composer.json

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, json, script

I want to add 3rd party module from artifacts in my project. required all modules with composer but when I run composer update at the end I have following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: Module 'Infortis_Ultimo' from '/var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/Ultimo' has been already defined in '/var/www/html/vendor/Infortis/Ultimo'. in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Component/ComponentRegistrar.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/Ultimo/registration.php(6): Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register('module', 'Infortis_Ultimo', '/var/www/html/a...')
#1 /var/www/html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): require_once('/var/www/html/a...')
#2 [internal function]: Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\{closure}('/var/www/html/a...')
#3 /var/www/html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): array_map(Object(Closure), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(33): Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\{closure}()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(70): require('/var/www/html/a...')
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(60): composerRequire5d53fefe7010e16b8a45c in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Component/ComponentRegistrar.php on line 50
Script ([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/) handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

something is wrong with the script https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d4DX.png how may I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this command:

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

Then run: `composer update`

Hope you help

Thanks...

Comment: I can't skip these scripts . its needed for pipelines

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because you have the same module in 2 destination :

```
- app/code/Infortis/Ultimo
- vendor/Infortis/Ultimo
```

Keep the module either in app/code or in vendor .

Comment: I remove them everythime. It creates on both place by itself.

Comment: check if you have the extension in composer.json